# Django UpdateView returns a blank rendered template

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am using django allauth for user authentication, in my adapter I have modified the `get_login_redirect_url` to redirect
new users to an `ONBOARD_URL` so they can complete registration process while regular users get the expected `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`

```
class UserAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def get_login_redirect_url(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated and (not request.user.name or not request.user.avatar
                                              or not request.user.mobile):
            url = settings.ONBOARD_URL
        else:
            url = settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL
        return resolve_url(url)
```

I have two functions handling the view and they both inherit from `UpdateView` and `DetailView` respectively.

```
class UpdateUserAfterSignupView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = UpdateUserAfterSignupForm
    template_name = 'users/user_form.html'
    context_object_name = 'user'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('users:detail')
```

```
class UserDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = User
    slug_field = 'username'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'username'
    template_name = 'users/user_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'user'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return get_object_or_404(self.model, username=self.request.user.username)
```

In my `DetailView`, if i leave out the `get_object` it returns a `PageNotFound 404`, but when its present as is, I get a blank page
in the rendered template. This is the template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<p>welcome {{user}}</p>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" value="submit">submit</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

and my url conf looks like this

```
[
    path('<str:username>/', views.UserDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('complete-signup/', views.UpdateUserAfterSignupView.as_view(), name='complete_signup'),
]
```

Again, all of these results in a blank rendered template, nothing at all. Could you please suggest things I should do
differently, or add. I can provide more information as required. Thank you

**EDIT**

`DetailView` template looks like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<p>{{user.name}}</p>
{% if user.avatar %}
<p><img src="{{ user.avatar.url }}" alt=""></p>
{% endif %}
<p>{{ user.mobile }}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

and my base template looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 2**
My template dir settings looks like this:

```
'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR / 'templates'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR / 'auth_templates'),
        ],
```

Comment: A `DetailView` has no `form`, so rendering the `{{ form }}` makes not much sense.

Comment: I’m not entirely sure I understand what you mean, but the template rendering the form is handled by the update view and not the detail view. Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: Could you please edit your question and post the complete template code for both templates, along with any base templates.

Comment: @evergreen I just did. Thank you

Comment: Do you have `{% extend ... %}` lines at the top of your `user_detail` and `user_form`  templates? If so, could you please add those.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is that I found in the answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52451320/django-allauth-urls-giving-blank-pages) that if you extend allauth's base template rather than your own it will cause the blank page problem (probably because it has different block names).

Comment: @evergreen Thank you again. So I followed that link, and this is what I have to say: I have two templates dir (check the edit) one houses the allauth templates and the other is the projects'. I just checked and I found base.html in allauth's dir, I'm thinking it should operate separately but it now looks like I might be wrong. Basically, both templates have a base.html although I don't see how that affects it I just checked by adding random text in both bases, and it still does not render anything.

Comment: Do you have `{% extends ... %}` lines at the top of your user_detail and user_form templates? (It has to be the first line.) They need to reference the base that is in your project directory. Otherwise the base won't be loaded.

Comment: Yes I did for both templates. It’s included at the very top.

Comment: One thing that I should have noticed earlier... Your detail url `<str:username>/` will match anything, including the string `complete-signup/`. You need to move `complete-signup/` above the details url so it will try to match that first. Or change the detail url to something like `user/<str:username>/`. However, I don't understand why you don't get a 404 in that case. Do you have additional urls above those?

Comment: @evergreen Indeed it was my URLs conf. I tried visiting the URL with an authenticated user, instead of a form I got nothing just like the detail URL. Made changes, it works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work finally, these are my changes:

**Adapter**

```
class UserAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def get_login_redirect_url(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated and (not request.user.name and not request.user.avatar and
                                              not request.user.mobile):
            return reverse('users:complete_signup', kwargs={'username': request.user.username})

        else:
            return resolve_url(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
```

**DetailView**

```
class UserDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = User
    slug_field = 'username'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'username'
    template_name = 'users/user_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'user'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return get_object_or_404(self.model, username=self.request.user.username)
```

**UpdateView**

```
class UpdateUserAfterSignupView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = User
    slug_field = 'username'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'username'
    form_class = UpdateUserAfterSignupForm
    template_name = 'users/user_update.html'
    context_object_name = 'user'
```

**URLs**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:username>/', views.UserDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<str:username>/complete-signup/', views.UpdateUserAfterSignupView.as_view(), name='complete_signup'),
]
```

My `detail` URL matched anything, `complete_signup` URL inclusive. These changes helped fixed that, the template now displays the expected form and not an empty page it did previously.